# Replace and remove string

Tags: ruby

From file `access_file.txt`, which has around 500 entries, with the content:

```
id\hzxcr
roll\85pol
id\byt65_d
rfc\myid
sub\aa_frt_09
.........
.........
```

I want to check if any of its lines is present in any of the files under the directory `:D:/Details/Ruby_new`, which has around 100+ files, with an extension ending i.e., `*-accessfile.txt`, as follows:

```
Name_accessfile.txt
ID_accessfile.txt
domain_accessfile.txt
roll_accessfile.txt
.......
.......
```

If present, I want to delete that instance or string, and save it in the same file. I don't want to create a new file or a backup file, but edit and save in the same file.

I came up with the following code:

```
value=File.open('D:\\my_work\\access_file.txt').read
value.gsub!(/\r\n?/, "\n")

value.each_line do |line|
    line.chomp!
    Dir.glob("D:/Details/Ruby_new/*-accessfile.txt") do |file_name|
      text = File.read(file_name)
      #print "FileName: #{file_name}\n"
      replace = text.gsub(/#{line}/, "")
      File.open(file_name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
    end
end
```

but I'm facing the following warning, and the string is not removed from the target files.

```
my_ruby.rb:10: warning: invalid subexp call: /id\hzxcr/ my_ruby:10:
warning: invalid subexp call: /id\hzxcr/
```

Looking for any suggestions.

Comment: It's an interesting question. By "every string in the below file line by line" do you mean "every string in every line in the below file?" or "every line in the below file"? By "delete only that instance or string" do you mean "delete only that line of the file?" Re "and save in the same file", how can you both delete it and save it? I suggest removing the request to not create a new file. (A detail, as one normally creates a new file, deletes the old file, then renames the new file.) The files being searched are not modified. Correct? Are matches case-indifferent? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: Are you primarily looking for any way it can be done or for a particularly efficient way of doing it? If the latter, can you say more about the entries in `access_file.txt`? For example, do all lines (as in your example) contain a backslash? What is the approximate minimum and maximum length of lines? *Etcetera*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `replace = text.gsub(line.strip, "")` instead of `replace = text.gsub(/#{line}/, "")`

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input, it resolved the warning but string is not getting removed in the target files. I'm sure i'm missing something silly while writing. any suggestions .Thanks again

Comment: Use my answer, and things will work for you as expected. I just tested it.

Comment: I tried your code, its not removing the string. May be the file needed to be closed.

Comment: The file gets closed since your operations are inside a block, there is something else going on with your files, try debugging it at each step.